# How can I make Docker store all data on D drive?

Tags: docker

I installed Docker and I want it to save images and containers in my folder D:\Docker. I [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon) that it can be done by writing the following into daemon.json:
`"data-root": "d:\\Docker"`
I did it. But now Docker cannot restart with an error:

> Failed to restart
>
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: Cancellation token
> triggered before we finished reading from the stream.    в
> HttpOverStream.ByLineReader.d__0.MoveNext()
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---    в
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    в
> HttpOverStream.Client.DialMessageHandler.d__9.MoveNext()
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---    в
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    в
> Docker.Core.Logging.LoggingMessageHandler.d__4.MoveNext() в
> C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Logging\LoggingMessageHandler.cs:строка
> 30
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---    в
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    в
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__58.MoveNext()
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---    в
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    в
> Docker.Core.HttpClientExtensions.d__0`1.MoveNext() в
> C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\HttpClientExtensions.cs:строка
> 16
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---    в
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    в
> Docker.ApiServices.LifecycleClient.d__10.MoveNext()
> в
> C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\LifecycleClient.cs:строка
> 122
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---    в
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    в Docker.LinuxkitDaemonStartup.d__5.MoveNext() в
> C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\LinuxkitDaemonStartup.cs:строка
> 30
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---    в
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    в
> Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.d__25.MoveNext() в
> C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:строка
> 160
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---    в
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    в
> Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.d__0.MoveNext()
> в
> C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:строка
> 20
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---    в
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    в
> Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.d__5.MoveNext()
> в
> C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:строка
> 29
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---    в
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    в
> Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.d__5.MoveNext()
> в
> C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:строка
> 38
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---    в
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    в
> Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.EngineStateMachine.d__14.MoveNext()
> в
> C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\EngineStateMachine.cs:строка
> 69
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---    в
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    в
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    в Docker.Engines.Engines.d__26.MoveNext() в
> C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\Engines.cs:строка
> 266

My daemon.json file contains this:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": false,
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  },
  "data-root": "d:\\Docker"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please help to share your deamon.json file

Comment: @Ashok, ok, done

Comment: Are you using Hyper-V

Comment: Try quitting Docker Desktop, and try to start it again

Comment: @Ashok, Yes, I tried doing it with Hyper-V and WSL. In both cases i got the result shown in the question. And I also tried to quit Docker Desktop and start it again. No effect.

Comment: What's the docker version you're using and is it a beta version?

Comment: @Ashok, I am using version 3.1.0 (51484) and as far as I know this is not beta.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228320/discussion-between-ashok-and-v-mor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting has moved many times during desktop and windows five year's marriage, from `graph:` to `data-root` to GUI's *advanced settings* section and counting.
Not sure if one of this is still working, but probably no, because in later versions this setting can be found in a different place.

It is `dataFolder` property in settings.json within `%AppData%\Roaming\Docker` folder.

For instance

```
"dataFolder": "C:\\ProgramData\\DockerDesktop\\vm-data"
```

I tested it working:

- in Windows 10
- with a recent version of Docker Desktop (>3.0.0)
- with both Hyper-V and WSL2
- with Linux containers

Actually this settings relocate the VM file associated with docker, moving "images and containers" but also volumes and other things.